# How does one fix: cannot find system Renviron Fatal error: unable to open the base package

Tags: r

I've been trying to get all the dependencies I need for R into a directory /isolated on CentOS.

When I run /isolated/usr/bin/R/bin/exec/R I get the following error:

```
cannot find system Renviron
Fatal error: unable to open the base package
```

I've set

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/isolated/usr/lib64:/isolated/usr/lib64/R/lib:/lib64
export R_HOME_DIR=/isolated/usr/lib64/R
```

Would appreciate any insights.

Comment: If you want an isolated R install, have you considered Docker or something? This sounds like something that requires intermediate to advanced Unix skills. Unless you can succinctly explain how you got to the current point, I'm not sure if anyone can help you with this.

Comment: Thanks @Marius, I have 1/2 decent UNIX skills -- I was looking for a resource that explains how to do it without docker -- docker is sometimes not an option -- I'm trying to standardize running R on lambda on AWS

Comment: @Marius -- succinct way to get the error:
git clone https://github.com/mattadams/Rtcl.git;
cd Rtcl; ./configure; make; make test

Comment: Should this be R_HOME instead of R_HOME_DIR ?

Comment: I get the error too. I installed R within a conda environment.